Freeing non allocated memory (c)
In the get_next_line function, I am using the pointer temp to free the memory allocated for leftover after it is being modified by strchr.
if I remove temp, the function leaks, but as it is now, I am freeing non allocated memory when freeing temp.
I've used a debugger to go through each steps of the function but I really do not see in what case temp could not point to allocated memory when it is freed.
char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *leftover;
    char        *next_line;
    char        *temp;

    if (BUFFER_SIZE <= 0 || fd < 0)
        return (NULL);
    if (!leftover)
        leftover = ft_read_from_file(fd, leftover);
    if (!leftover)
        return (NULL);
    next_line = ft_find_line(leftover);
    temp = leftover;
    leftover = ft_strchr(leftover, '\n');
    if (leftover)
        leftover++;
    else
        free(temp);
    return (next_line);
}

char    *ft_read_from_file(int fd, char *leftover)
{
    char        *buffer;
    long long   bytes_read;

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
    if (!buffer)
        return (NULL);
    while (!ft_strchr(buffer, '\n'))
    {   
        bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if (bytes_read == -1)
        {
            free(buffer);
            return (NULL);
        }
        else if (bytes_read == 0)
            break ;
        else
            buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
        leftover = ft_strjoin(leftover, buffer);
    }
    free(buffer);
    return (leftover);
}

char    *ft_find_line(char *leftover)
{
    char    *str;
    int     i;
    int     j;

    j = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (leftover[i] != '\n' && leftover[i])
        i++;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 2));
    while (i > j)
    {
        str[j] = leftover[j];
        j++;
    }
    if (leftover[j] == '\n')
    {
        str[j] = leftover[j];
        j++;
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i] && s[i] != (char)c && i < BUFFER_SIZE)
        i++;
    if (s[i] == (char)c)
        return ((char *)&s[i]);
    return ((void *)0);
}

char    *ft_strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    int     i;
    int     j;
    char    *str;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    if (!s1 && !s2)
        return (NULL);
    if (!s1)
        return (ft_strdup(s2));
    str = malloc((ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if (str == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (s1[i])
    {
        str[j++] = s1[i++];
    }
    i = 0;
    while (s2[i] && i < BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        str[j++] = s2[i++];
    }
    str[j] = '\0';
    free((void *)s1);
    return (str);
}

char    *ft_strdup(const char *s1)
{
    int     i;
    int     size;
    char    *ptr;

    i = 0;
    size = ft_strlen(s1);
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1);
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (s1[i])
    {
        ptr[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }
    ptr[i] = '\0';
    return (ptr);
}

int ft_strlen(const char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i])
        i++;
    return (i);
}


I really do not see in what case temp could not point to allocated memory when it is freed. leftover++; is obvious.  If leftover starts out referring to allocated memory, leftover++; results in a value that does not refer to allocated memory: "if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined."

So when i increment leftover it increments temp as well ?

To free memory, you need a pointer to the beginning of the dynamically allocated memory block. As currently implemented, get_next_line() can't necessarily do that. There are also other issues in the code. . . .

Scenario: first call of get_next_line() uses ft_read_from_file() to fetch a buffer of data from the file. Perhaps the buffer contains 5 1/2 lines of text. It uses ft_find_line() to crate a buffer containing the first line that it can return to the caller. It then advances leftover to point to where the second line in the buffer starts. It does not maintain the pointer to the beginning, so future calls can never properly free the buffer. . . .

There are more issues. Do you really want to extend the buffer when it already has a full, unprocessed line in it? (e.g. Have processed 1st line, but still have 4 1/2 lines of text in buffer) What if there is a line that is longer than BUFFER_SIZE? And in ft_strjoin(), why do you have the check against BUFFER_SIZE in while (s2[i] && i < BUFFER_SIZE)

Static variables are not your friends. If you need buffered I/O, C has a built-in facility for that in <stdio.h>. If you need buffered I/O but cannot for some reason use <stdio.h>, roll your own but without any stattics. Instead, use a struct with a file descriptor, a buffer, and a counter. Use it like you would use FILE.

So when i increment leftover it increments temp as well ?  If leftover has the same value as temp, you'd better not free temp because the next time around you'll be using freed memory.

To fix issue with you must keep temp pointing to the first byte of allocated memory. In your example that would be making temp static and moving assignment into if statement right after call of ft_read_from_file.
After that your function still will not work properly but problem with leak / free of temp should be fixed.
